# Why does concat Series to DataFrame with index matching columns not work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I want to append a Series to a DataFrame where Series's index matches DataFrame's columns using `pd.concat`, but it gives me surprises:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'])
sr = pd.Series(data=[1,2], index=['a', 'b'], name=1)
pd.concat([df, sr], axis=0)
Out[11]: 
     a    b    0
a  NaN  NaN  1.0
b  NaN  NaN  2.0
```

What I expected is of course:

```
df.append(sr)
Out[14]: 
   a  b
1  1  2
```

It really surprises me that `pd.concat` is not index-columns aware. So is it true that if I want to concat a Series as a new row to a DF, then I can only use `df.append` instead?

Comment: Try with `axis=1`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga didn't work either. As it turns out it has the same output as when axis=0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Need `DataFrame` from `Series` by [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose:

```
a = pd.concat([df, sr.to_frame(1).T])
print (a)
   a  b
1  1  2
```

Detail:

```
print (sr.to_frame(1).T)
   a  b
1  1  2
```

Or use [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement):

```
df.loc[1] = sr
print (df)
   a  b
1  1  2
```

Answer (score 1):

"df.loc[1] = sr" will drop the column if it isn't in df

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a','b'])
sr = pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3})
df.loc[1] = sr
```

df will be like:

```
   a  b
1  1  2
```