# How to convert DataFrame.append() to pandas.concat()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

In pandas 1.4.0: `append()` was deprecated, and the docs say to use `concat()` instead.

> FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be
> removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.

**Codeblock in question:**

```python
def generate_features(data, num_samples, mask):
    """
    The main function for generating features to train or evaluate on.
    Returns a pd.DataFrame()
    """
    logger.debug("Generating features, number of samples", num_samples)
    features = pd.DataFrame()

    for count in range(num_samples):
        row, col = get_pixel_within_mask(data, mask)
        input_vars = get_pixel_data(data, row, col)
        features = features.append(input_vars)
        print_progress(count, num_samples)

    return features
```

**These are the two options I've tried, but did not work:**

```
features = pd.concat([features],[input_vars])
```

and

```
pd.concat([features],[input_vars])
```

**This is the line that is deprecated and throwing the error:**

```
features = features.append(input_vars)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can store the DataFrames generated in the loop in a list and concatenate them with `features` once you finish the loop.

In other words, replace the loop:

```
for count in range(num_samples):
    # .... code to produce `input_vars`
    features = features.append(input_vars)        # remove this `DataFrame.append`
```

with the one below:

```
tmp = []                                  # initialize list
for count in range(num_samples):
    # .... code to produce `input_vars`
    tmp.append(input_vars)                        # append to the list, (not DF)
features = pd.concat(tmp)                         # concatenate after loop
```

You can certainly concatenate in the loop but it's more efficient to do it only once.

Comment: From personal experience, each append can individually take almost as long as the entire concat, so the time savings by doing it once at the end can be massive.

Comment: It is very unfortunate that they are deprecating append for dataframes.  With my code, creating the dataframe using the temporary list as shown here results in my code running 10X slower.

Answer (score 5):

This will "append" the blank df and prevent errors in the future by using the concat option

```
features= pd.concat([features, input_vars])
```

However, still, without having access to actually data and data structures this would be hard to test replicate.

Comment: On the official Pandas docs for the latest release, you will see that .append() was deprecated. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html They say I should use concat() instead, but I can't get it to work. I will keep exploring the pandas docs.

Comment: I updated my answer to use the concat thank you for pointing out the docs sorry if I missed them before

Comment: This directly fixes the op's mistake e.g. [features],[input_vars] should be [features, input_vars]. However in the case of a loop like the op, the other answer is far more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have a list of dataframes called `collector`, e.g. for cryptocurrencies, and you want to harvest first rows from two particular columns from each datafarme in our 'collector'. You do as follows

```
pd.concat([cap[['Ticker', 'Market Cap']].iloc[:1] for cap in collector] )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another unpleasant edge case here: If `input_vars` is a series (not a dataframe) that represents one row to be appended to `features`, the deprecated use of `features = features.append(input_vars)` works fine and adds one row to the dataframe.

But the version with concat `features = pd.concat([features, input_vars])` does something different and produces lots of NaNs. To get this to work, you need to convert the series to a dataframe:

```
features = pd.concat([features, input_vars.to_frame().T])
```

See also this question: [Why does concat Series to DataFrame with index matching columns not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47090309/why-does-concat-series-to-dataframe-with-index-matching-columns-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can bring it back by creating a module

```
import pandas as pd


def my_append(self, x, ignore_index=False):
    if ignore_index:
        return pd.concat([self, x])
    else:
        return pd.concat([self, x]).reset_index(drop=True)


if not hasattr(pd.DataFrame, "append"):
    setattr(pd.DataFrame, "append", my_append)
```

This will add the implementation and can be tested as follows

```py
import pandas as pd
import lib.pandassupport


def test_append_ignore_index_is_true():
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            {"Name": "John", "Age": 25, "City": "New York"},
            {"Name": "Emily", "Age": 30, "City": "San Francisco"},
            {"Name": "Michael", "Age": 35, "City": "Chicago"},
        ]
    )
    new_row = pd.DataFrame([{"Name": "Archie", "Age": 27, "City": "Boston"}])
    df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
    print(df)
    assert df.equals(
        pd.DataFrame(
            [
                {"Name": "John", "Age": 25, "City": "New York"},
                {"Name": "Emily", "Age": 30, "City": "San Francisco"},
                {"Name": "Michael", "Age": 35, "City": "Chicago"},
                {"Name": "Archie", "Age": 27, "City": "Boston"},
            ],
            [0, 1, 2, 0],
        )
    )


def test_append():
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            {"Name": "John", "Age": 25, "City": "New York"},
            {"Name": "Emily", "Age": 30, "City": "San Francisco"},
            {"Name": "Michael", "Age": 35, "City": "Chicago"},
        ]
    )
    new_row = pd.DataFrame([{"Name": "Archie", "Age": 27, "City": "Boston"}])
    df = df.append(new_row)
    assert df.equals(
        pd.DataFrame(
            [
                {"Name": "John", "Age": 25, "City": "New York"},
                {"Name": "Emily", "Age": 30, "City": "San Francisco"},
                {"Name": "Michael", "Age": 35, "City": "Chicago"},
                {"Name": "Archie", "Age": 27, "City": "Boston"},
            ],
            [0, 1, 2, 3],
        )
    )
```